# Invalidate not working (winforms & xna)

Tags: xna, c#, windows-forms

I'm using winforms with xna.
Everything's working so far except for the drawing because invalidate won't refresh the screen unless repeated. This is the initial code I had:

```
        protected override void Draw()
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            tileSheet.Draw(spriteBatch);
            foreach (Image img in selector)
                img.Draw(spriteBatch);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
```

I placed a breakpoint and it is calling the draw method but nothing is changing on the screen but when I do this:

```
protected override void Draw()
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        tileSheet.Draw(spriteBatch);
        foreach (Image img in selector)
            img.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();

        Invalidate();
    }
```

It works! but the problem is that everything gets frozen and it seems to get caught up in an Invalidate loop. But why does the latter work but not to former? I've been working at this for hours now and I can't understand what's going wrong :/.

I feel like it's something simple but I can't wrap my head around it.

ps. I've also tried Update and Refresh and they don't work either.

Comment: @congusbongus I've checked that already. I already have that in my code and it doesn't work.

Comment: @floAr yea I know it's my question because nobody answered this one.